# Shows no error but also doesnt give any output

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying to take two strings as input and combine them and all their individual character into a vector.

Full Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1;
    string str2;

    cin>>str1>>str2;

    vector<char>vec;

    for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
        vec[i]=str1[i];
    }

    int k=str1.length();
    for(int i=0;i<str2.length();i++){
        vec[k]=str2[i];
        k++;
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
        cout<<vec[i];
    }
}
```

What am I missing?
Am I missing a concept about strings here?

I am trying to take two strings as input and combine them and all their individual character into a vector.

In terminal code shows **no error**, takes input for both strings, but shows **no output**.

Comment: Use `vec.push_back()` instead of `vec[i]`

Comment: `vec` is empty. `vec[i]` exhibits undefined behavior for any value of `i`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: When you learn C++ use `vec.at(i)` instead of square brackets.

Comment: @igortandetnik I now understand what I missed. Thank you .

Comment: @samVarshavchik i never used that header until today, felt lazy and wrote that. Never again.Thank you for insight.

Comment: Side notes: (1) [more info why I shouldn't use #include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) (2) [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @wohlstad I will follow this practice from now on. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare a vector of chars `vec` with no initial size. At this point, `vec` has a size of 0, meaning that it can't store any elements (without getting into too much detail). Then, you attempt to modify the vector with `vec[i]=str1[i]`. Since `vec` doesn't actually have any storage to store the elements, you're modifying memory you don't own. This is a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), and kills the program. When a segmentation fault occurs, there is no output produced, hence why there isn't output.

You should allocate memory for `vec` using the method `resize`:

```
//...
vector<char> vec;
vec.resize(str1.length() + str2.length());

for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
//...
```

There shouldn't be a segmentation fault after this.

Comment: Didn't knew that information. I can't thank you enough for taking the time to share your knowledge on Stack Overflow. Many thanks!